# pass the number of link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html.twig file with this

```
{% set num= 1%}
{% for idea in ideas %}

    <div class="add">
        <a href="#"> Comentar </a>|<a href="#" rel="like{{num}}"> Tomado </a>|<a href="#">Valorar</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% set num= num +1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

so depend of the number of ideas I have more o less likes, like this

```
<a rel="like1" href="#"> Tomado </a>
<a rel="like2" href="#"> Tomado </a>
<a rel="like3" href="#"> Tomado </a>
```

If I want to do a click in jquery,but how I indicate the number of link, the value of num variable

```
   $("a[rel='like']").click(function(){
            alert($("a[rel='like']").text());
    });
```

any idea!

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do? Do you want the number of links on the page or the index of the link that was clicked?

Comment: That's a TWIG HTML file. It IS HTML. BTW, you could use `{{ loop.index }}` instead of increasing a `num` variable

Comment: @Touki: There might be HTML, but it does not make it a HTML file.

Comment: @Amberlamps TWIG compiles files into a given markup language. In that case, HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you want the value of the `rel` attribute.
If that's true, you should try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kakashi/Uqqpr/

My solution uses the `attr` method to obtain the value of the `rel` attribute.

**Update**
It appears you want the number contained in the rel attribute, i.e. you want "1" when it's "like1", "2" when it's "like2", etc.
If so, this solution will do that:

http://jsfiddle.net/kakashi/Uqqpr/1/

**Update 2 -- accounting for multiple digit "likes" **

http://jsfiddle.net/kakashi/Uqqpr/2/
This version uses regular expressions to capture the number at the end.

Answer (score 2):

for this you can tryout this jquery selector [jQuery('[attribute^="value"]')](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

code it like this

```
 $("a[rel^='like']").click(function(){
            alert($(this).attr("rel"));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`startsWith`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector like this:

```
$("a[rel^='like']").click(function(){
    var theNumber = this.rel.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
});
```

Chances are, you don't even need to parse the number out of your rel attribute (plus you should really be using a data attribute for that):

```
$("a[rel^='like']").click(function(){
    var theNumber = $(this).index(); 
});
```

Example using `data` attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-num="{{num}}">

$("a[rel^='like']").click(function(){
    var theNumber = $(this).data("num"); 
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/3FVwY/)